# How does lambda functions works in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

Is there any enviroment where `handler.js` is running? And if so what if somehow run `sudo rm -rf ~/` in AWS lambda?

How do think what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a Lambda function as a managed (short-lived) docker container (although Micro-VM would be more correct, as we learned at re:Invent 2018). You define the compute and RAM resources your "container" has to run a function.

As the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html?shortFooter=true) states, you get the following environment:

> The underlying AWS Lambda execution environment includes the following
>   software and libraries.
>
> - Operating system – Amazon Linux
> - AMI – amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2
> - Linux kernel – 4.14.77-70.59.amzn1.x86_64
> - AWS SDK for JavaScript – 2.290.0
> - SDK for Python (Boto 3) – 3-1.7.74 botocore-1.10.74

Furthermore you're provided with some temporary storage (at the moment 500MB) at `/tmp/`.

AWS tries to re-run the handler function for each Lambda-Invocation (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html?shortFooter=true) for more details), if there is already a "container" running, so I'd imagine you could break your own container - although it apparently [doesn't have sudo privileges](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=773800), so there's limited impact that you can have with your `sudo rm -rf`.